# How to get index ids from an index in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am having trouble getting the index ids from an index using the java api for elasticsearch.

When creating an IndexResponse I can get the IndexResponse id from the "IndexResponse" object. When creating an index I do not specify the id so I let elasticsearch handle this. How can I get a listing of the ids for a specific index?

I would then iterate through the ids to submit other requests (i.e. GET, DELETE).

I am using the java api and not spring-data. The version is 1.7 for those interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieving all of the IDs from an index is generally a terrible idea, which gets more terrible depending on how large your index is.  If you really need it, consider using a `scroll` query to achieve what you want.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/scroll.html#CO33-1

The guide has is written for Elasticsearch 2.x, but it works for Elasticsearch 5.x if you're using that.

Essentially how it works is this:
Create a scroll window of size `x`, return the first 1000 results without the overhead of scoring, analysis, etc.  The resources are allocated by Elasticsearch for a time of `y`.  The first response returns not only the first `x` documents, but returns a `_scroll_id` that can be used to fetch the next `x` documents.

```
GET http://yourhost:9200/old_index/_search?scroll=1m 
{
    "query": { "match_all": {}},
    "sort" : ["_doc"], 
    "size":  1000
}
```

Say the response to the above query is something like...

```
{
  "_scroll_id": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
  "took": 15,
  "timed_out": false,
  "terminated_early": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1027,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        ...
```

You would then use the `_scroll_id` like so to fetch the next `x` results.

```
GET http://yourhost:9200/_search/scroll
{
    "scroll": "1m", 
    "scroll_id" : "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
}
```

It returns a response similar to the above.  Ensure you rip out the `_scroll_id` from each request response and use it in the next.  Using all of these responses, you can iterate through the hits and rip out the IDs.